# Wordpress Customizer page different to Live page

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am a newbie to wordpress so excuse me if this is a silly question.

My page is giving odd behaviour. In the customizer page(ie with all the settings to change colors etc. ) The site works perfectly. All featured posts pop up where they are supposed to, with font colors being right and all the rest.

Now when I close the customizer and view the page it goes oddly, the font color changes in the featured post section so it is invisible unless highlighted, and new posts do not show up with the required tags there.

I've tried deleting the cache as well.

Comment: Can you provide some link or code or maybe the wordpress theme that you are using?

Comment: I am using Ridizain. Which is a derivative of Twenty Fourteen.https://wordpress.org/themes/ridizain

Comment: Might be a given but is there a "save changes" you are forgetting to click?

Comment: Every change I make I click the save and publish button. As an aside it is running on my WAMP server on my local machine